# Trying to serialize with JSON a save method in my Ruby Hangman game

Tags: json, ruby, serialization

I'm trying to get my save_game() method to work, nothing is getting written to the JSON file. This is my first assignment working with JSON and serialization in general. I'm not quite sure where I'm even going wrong.

These are my serialization methods:

```
  def to_json
    JSON.generate({array: @array, filestuff: @filestuff, random_word: @random_word, cipher: @cipher, random_word2: @random_word2, counter: @counter})
  end

  def load
    game_file = File.read("saved.json")
    data = JSON.parse(game_file)
    @cipher = data["cipher"]
    @random_word2 = data["random_word2"]
    @counter = data["counter"]
  end

  def save_game(string)
    game_file = File.new("saved.json","w") 
    game_file.write(string)
    game_file.close
  end
```

This is my program, on line 92 I try to call my save_game method.

```
require 'json'
load 'display.rb'

class Hangman
  attr_accessor :name
  @name = name

  def initialize
    puts "What is your name?"
    @name = gets.chomp
    puts "
################################################
                   HANGMAN
################################################

               _________
              |        
              |       |
              |       O
              |      /|\\
              |       |
              |      / \\
              |
              -----------------
Welcome #{@name} to Hangman. The computer will generate
a 5-12 letter random word. You will try to guess
that word one letter at a time. Try to solve the
puzzle before time runs out! 


"

  end
end

class Gameplay
  attr_accessor :array, :filestuff, :random_word, :cipher, :random_word2, :counter
  def initialize
  @array = []
  @filestuff = File.foreach('5text.txt') do |x|
      chomped = x.chomp
      @array << chomped if (chomped.length >= 5 and chomped.length <= 12)
    end
  @random_word = @array.sample
  @cipher = @random_word.gsub(/[a-z]/, '*').split(//)
  @random_word2 = @random_word.split(//)
  @counter = 5

  def to_json
    JSON.generate({array: @array, filestuff: @filestuff, random_word: @random_word, cipher: @cipher, random_word2: @random_word2, counter: @counter})
  end

  def load
    game_file = File.read("saved.json")
    data = JSON.parse(game_file)
    @cipher = data["cipher"]
    @random_word2 = data["random_word2"]
    @counter = data["counter"]
  end

  def save_game(string)
    game_file = File.new("saved.json","w") 
    game_file.write(string)
    game_file.close
  end

  def choice(n)
    @random_word2.each_with_index do |i,index|
      if i == n
        @cipher[index] = i 
      end 
    end 
      if n == @random_word2.join.to_s
        puts "You win"
        puts "would you like to start another game? Y/N"
        new_game = gets.chomp
        if new_game == "Y"
          Hangman.new
          else exit 
        end
      end
      if @random_word2.include?(n) == false
        @counter -= 1
        display
        puts "#{@counter} guesses remaining."
        puts "To save press 1"
        save = gets.chomp
        if save == "1"

#Will not save 
          save_game($b.to_json)
        end
      end
      if @counter == 0
        puts "would you like to start another game? Y/N"
        new_game = gets.chomp
        if new_game == "Y"
          else exit 
        end
      end 
        puts @cipher.join 
  end

  @counter = 5
  while @counter > 0 
    choice(gets.chomp)
  end

 end 
end
Hangman.new
$b = Gameplay.new
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to [`close`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/IO.html#method-i-close) the file in order to make sure your output is actually written to the disk ("flushed"). You can manually, call `close`:

```
def save_game(string)
  game_file = File.new("saved.json","w") 
  game_file.write(string)
  game_file.close
end
```

or, you can use [`File.open`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/File.html#method-c-open), which takes a block and `close`s the file when the block ends:

```
File.open("saved.json", "w") do |game_file|
  game_file.write(string)
end
```

Since, writing to the disk is a slow operation, Ruby (and all languages that I can think of right now) will hold off on actually writing the file until it has accumulated a certain amount of text in a buffer. Once it has reached this limit, it will *flush* the buffer and write everything in it to disk. In order to make sure all your text is actually written when trying to write a file, you need to call `close` on the file, and as part of closing it, Ruby will flush whatever is left in its buffer.

There are other ways of making sure your content is flushed but when you're just starting to learn about this stuff, it should suffice to just make sure to always `close` files when you're done reading or writing them.

Comment: Still nothing saved to my file, but edited to "open". I tried both versions.

Comment: If you use `open` you should pass it a block. Using `open` without a block is the exact same thing as doing `File.new` and so would need to be closed manually

Comment: Will edit now. Tried on my computer with no luck still.